# Anaconda Prompt invokes AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm just started with Python, so please bear with me

I'm aware this question has been asked multiple times before, such as : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169218/attributeerror-namespacepath-object-has-no-attribute-sort) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475184/anaconda-prompt-will-not-start-namespacepath)

However, I can't solve this issue

I think I have 2 version of `pip` on my machine : the first one is installed on the Windows OS, and the other is in the Anaconda folder (`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe`)

People said I need to upgrade my pip version (`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`) to solve this bug, but I can't upgrade my pip (the one in the Anaconda folder) because of this very same error :

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Please kindly help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cloned source codes of `setuptools` and `pip` from github. Then I installed them via Anaconda Prompt. It worked for me.